# Centos install chrome failed

Tags: linux, google-chrome, centos

I follow [this](http://www.tecmint.com/install-google-chrome-on-redhat-centos-fedora-linux/) step to install chrome on centos linux, but when I run application `yum install google-chrome-stable`

I get this:

> error: package:google-chrome-stable-35.0.1916.153-1.x86_64(google-chrome) requires: libstdc++.so.6

I have checked my file `libstdc++.so.6` at `/usr/lib`

So, anyone known how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide yum update before installing anything (i.e. particularly after updating yum repository).

In your case, you should give

```
 yum update
```

then, proceed with installing the software required, it might fix the issue

```
 yum install google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you submitted specifically states:

> Update : Sadly, the Google Chrome browser no longer supports the most famous commercial distribution RHEL 6.x and its free clones such as CentOS and Scientific Linux.
>
> Yes, they’ve discontinued support for RHEL 6.X version as of Google Chrome and on other side, latest Firefox and Opera browsers run successfully on the same platforms.

So there, you can't install Chrome on (I assume) CentOS 6. I get the same error you posted when trying on my CentOS 6.7 system.

You have to upgrade to CentOS 7, use another browser, or use this script http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/ (haven't tested it myself but countless other people have used it).

Answer (score 0):

Please check libstdc++.so.6 in /usr/lib64/ directory.